# Module invoke webform redirecting validation

Tags: webforms

On one page I have this code, that loads my [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform):

```
$block = module_invoke('webform', 'block_view', '660');
print render($block['content']);
```

But when I click on submit button, validation leads me to another page (webform page). How  can I stay on current page, where webform is loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `admin/block` and edit your webform block and check "`Show all webform pages in block`" and all errors display in block not in node.

This should resolved the problem, however you can check more about this problem here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1308806

Comment: Now I have new error: On submit button, fields border become red, but error messages are shown after page reload, not after form submition.

Comment: @josaric Please add that as a follow up question , we would be glad to help on that. The above answer seems to answer the original question :)